# How to properly implement paywalled content

Tags: seo, html, schema.org, paywall

To avoid cloaking, I'm planing to indicate [paywalled content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/paywalled-content) on reviews, but I'm struggling how to format both JSON-LD and HTML:

- Should I add `hasPart` and `isAccessibleForFree` keywords for each `Review`?
  (apparently `LocalBusiness` doesn't accept `hasPart` according [to the testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool))
- Do I need to add the **paywalled property** `description` for search
  engines?
- In the HTML, I'm generating a "Lorem ipsum" `description`
  instead to the actual text and blurring it using CSS. The blurred
  text has the class `paywall`, will Google and other SE penalize the
  site because of the arbitrary nonsense text? will `description` be
  considered as cloaking in this case (since search engines and users
  have different content)?

Below is a small example to test, there may be hundreds of reviews.

```json
{  
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "@id": "http://localBusiness.example.com",
  "name": "Example",
  "image": "http://localBusiness.example.com/image.jpg",
  "aggregateRating":{  
     "@type":"AggregateRating",
     "ratingValue":"3.75",
     "reviewCount":"2"
  },
  "review":[  
     {  
        "@type":"Review",
        "@id":"http://localBusiness.example.com/Review/1",
        "author":"Anonym",
        "name":"Review 1",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "datePublished":"2017-07-19",
        "reviewRating":{  
           "@type":"Rating",
           "ratingValue":"4"
        },
        "isAccessibleForFree": "False",
        "hasPart": {
           "@type": "WebPageElement",
           "isAccessibleForFree": "False",
           "cssSelector" : ".paywall"
        }
     },
     {  
        "@type":"Review",
        "@id":"http://localBusiness.example.com/Review/2",
        "author":"Anonym",
        "name":"Review 2",
        "description":"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non",
        "datePublished":"2017-10-19",
        "reviewRating":{  
           "@type":"Rating",
           "ratingValue":"3.5"
        },
        "isAccessibleForFree": "False",
        "hasPart": {
           "@type": "WebPageElement",
           "isAccessibleForFree": "False",
           "cssSelector" : ".paywall"
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Description should actual values from the page and also you should use flexible sampling > https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7532484

Comment: I'm already using flexible sampling even though is no longer required. Users can inspect the page, that's why I substitute the content, the keyword `description` is also optional, I may remove it from the JSON-LD.

Answer (score 1):

- Google notes in the cited documentation, this implementation is only possible for the type CreativeWork. I don't know, whether this kind of markup, even if validated errorfree by testing tool, is correct by design,
- Not a LocalBusiness should be divided into hasPart-parts,
- Your review should be marked up as having hasPart, and than as containing an array of multiple reviews,
- loremIpsum in HTML would be in my opinion definitely harmful - it is a sign of a website, which isn't finally ready for publishing.

**Correct, means *valide*, markup would be**:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{  
"@context": "http://www.schema.org",
"@type": "LocalBusiness",
"name": "Example",
"image": "http://localBusiness.example.com/image.jpg",
"mainEntityOfPage": {
"@type": "WebPage",
"@id": "http://localBusiness.example.com",
"hasPart":    
{
"@type": "WebPageElement",
"aggregateRating":{  
"@type":"AggregateRating",
"ratingValue":"3.75",
"reviewCount":"2"
},
"isAccessibleForFree": "False",
"cssSelector" : ".paywall",
"review":[
{
"@type": "Review",
"author": "John Doe",
"datePublished": "2006-05-04",
"name": "A masterpiece of literature",
"reviewBody": "I really enjoyed this book. It captures the essential challenge people face as they try make sense of their lives and grow to adulthood.",
"reviewRating": {
"@type": "Rating",
"ratingValue": "5"
}
},
{
"@type": "Review",
"author": "Bob Smith",
"datePublished": "2006-06-15",
"name": "A good read.",
"reviewBody": "Catcher in the Rye is a fun book. It's a good book to read.",
"reviewRating": {
"@type": "Rating",
"ratingValue": "5"
}
}
]
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I think my `mainEntityOfPage` is a list of reviews for a specific `LocalBusiness` (i.e. `example.com/company/reviews` , `example.com/another-company/reviews`), will it be considered as 
`CreativeWork` if I swap `LocalBusiness` with `Review`? In your markup you have described the @id of `mainEntityOfPage` with the same URL of the page, it's a redundancy, isn't it?